# Issue trying to return key and values inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-loops

First time poster here. I'm trying to create a simple conversion program on Python for a project I am working on as part of a course I am enrolled in.

I am trying to return the conversion for a number of length units based on a starting unit. To do this I am trying to use nested dictionaries. It has to be via a CLI terminal so i'm not allowed to use ttinker or anything like that to provide a GUI.

I am trying to return it in the format:

x centimetres converted equals:

x kilometres
x metres
x miles etc.

Instead I am getting this return with my current version of code(although I do expect it to return like this, but this is the closest to the result I want I have came yet):

x centimetres converted equals:
x
x
x
kilometres
metres
miles

My code at present looks like:

```
            len_selection = pyip.inputMenu(["Nanometre", "Micrometre", "Millimetre", "Centimetre", "Metre", "Kilometre", "Inch", "Foot", "Yard", "Mile", "Nautical Mile"], numbered=True)
            print("\nEnter the number of your required unit\n")
            len_value = pyip.inputNum("\nPlease enter the length to convert:")

            length_conversion_factors = {
                'kilometre': {'metre': 0.001, 'centimetre': 0.00001, 'millimetre': 0.000001,
                'micrometre': 0.000000001, 'nanometre': 0.000000000001, 'mile': 1.60934,
                'yard': 0.000914397727272727, 'foot': 0.000304799242424242, 'inch': 2.53999368686869,
                'nautical mile': 1.852},

                'metre': {'kilometre': 1000, 'centimetre': 0.01, 'millimetre': 0.001, 'micrometre': 0.000001,
                'nanometre': 0.000000001, 'mile': 1609.34, 'yard': 0.914397727272727, 'foot': 0.304799242424242,
                'inch': 0.0253999368686869, 'nautical mile': 1852},

                'centimetre': {'kilometre': 100000, 'metre': 100, 'millimetre': 0.1,
                'micrometre': 0.0001, 'nanometre': 0.0000001, 'mile': 160934,
                'yard': 91.4397727272727, 'foot': 30.4799242424242, 'inch': 2.53999368686869,
                'nautical mile': 185200}}

            length_key = len_selection.lower()

            print(f"\n{len_value} {len_selection}s converted equals:")

            if length_key in length_conversion_factors:
                for value in length_conversion_factors[length_key]:
                    conv_value = len_value * float(length_conversion_factors[length_key][value])
                    print(conv_value)
                for key in length_conversion_factors[length_key]:
                    print(key)
```

I have spent a day and a half on this already and I am pulling my hair out at this point.

I have tried the likes of 'for key, value in length_conversion_factors[length_key]:'so it all runs in the one for loop and I get a Value error saying too much to be unpacked. I also tried unpacking the keys first, storing them in a variable and then using a print statement but no joy with it either.

I've tried using 'return key' and 'return conv_value' and then using a separate print statement on those but cant seem to get it to work at all.

I' know I'm probably missing something very simple. many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lets you print more than one thing in a statement:

```py
if length_key in length_conversion_factors:
    for value in length_conversion_factors[length_key]:
        conv_value = len_value * float(length_conversion_factors[length_key][value])
        print(conv_value, value)
```

This is giving me output like:

```
1 kilometres converted equals:
0.001 metre
1e-05 centimetre
1e-06 millimetre
1e-09 micrometre
```

which appears to be what you wanted. You can even replace the final print statement with an f-string, just like the one that appears already in the code: `print(f"{conv_value} {value}s")`

Comment: Thank you so much....I can't believe it was that simple after all that. I had tried using key in the print statement on a previous attempt but never thought about using value. You have saved whats left of my teeth after countless hours of gnashing!